# How to make a FeatureClass from a FeatureClassToken?

Tags: c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

I need to create various objects - FeatureClasses, Tables, CodedValueDomains and like. I've found several [guides](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProConcepts-DDL) on creating a `Description` object (like `FeatureDatasetDescription`) and a `Token` (e.g. `FeatureClassToken`) object from it. However, the `FeatureClassToken` is not yet the object to be built, it doesn't have the properties and methods of a `FeatureClass`, even though the instructions on DDL not always distinguish between the two.

Casting the `FeatureClassToken` to a `FeatureClass` might work in VisualBasic, but in C#, it throws an error (`Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'ArcGIS.Core.Data.DDL.FeatureClassToken' to 'ArcGIS.Core.Data.FeatureClass'`). So, what to do?